# How to show $ \frac{Q_{k}(1-z^2)-zP_{k}(1-z^2)}{Q_{k}(1-z^2)+zP_{k}(1-z^2)}=\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^{2k+1} $ analytically?

Tags: special-functions

Let \begin{eqnarray*}
 P_{k}(z)={_2F_1}(-k,\frac{1}{2}-k;
-2k; z),
\ \label{e0} Q_{k}(z)={_2F_1}(-k,-\frac{1}{2}-k; -2k; z)
,
\end{eqnarray*}
 where $k\ge 1$ is an integer.

How to show 
 \begin{eqnarray*}\label{e1}
 \frac{Q_{k}(1-z^2)-zP_{k}(1-z^2)}{Q_{k}(1-z^2)+zP_{k}(1-z^2)}=\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^{2k+1}
 \end{eqnarray*}
analytically?

Comment: Seems to me your $P$ and $Q$ are related to Legendre functions. Have you checked [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those hypergeometric functions are essentially Chebyshev polynomials...
$$
{}_2F_1 \Biggl(\biggl[-k,\frac{1}{2} - k\biggr],[-2k],1 - z^{2}\Biggr) =
\frac{\bigl(1 - z^{2}\bigr)^{k} U_{2k} \biggl(\bigl(1 - z^{2}\bigr)^{-1/2}\biggr)}{2^{2 k}}
$$
and the other one in terms of $T_{2k+1}$.  Using the relation between the Chebyshev polynomials and the multiple angle formulas suggests the substitution $z=\tanh \theta$.  Then the left-hand side becomes
$$
\Bigl(\operatorname{cosh} \bigl((1 + 2 k) \theta\bigr) - \operatorname{sinh} \bigl((1 + 2 k) \theta\bigr)\Bigr)^{2}
$$
and the right-hand side becomes
$$
\Biggl(\frac{1 - \operatorname{tanh} (\theta)}{1 + \operatorname{tanh} (\theta)}\Biggr)^{1 + 2 k}
$$
Converting to exponentials finishes.